# Angular UI Grid Multiple Columns Editable At The Same Time

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

I am using Angular UI Grid and I want to know if it is possible to make multiple fields, on multiple rows 'appear' editable at the same time. From a user perspective it is impossible to tell at a glance which fields are editable. The best I have been able to get is the setting 'enableCellEditOnFocus', but this still only allows edit when a user specifically clicks on a cell.

```
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [   
    { name: 'age', enableCellEditOnFocus:true  }
];
```

Comment: You can use cellTemplates to allow editing

Answer (score 0):

After some searching and that helpful suggestion by Austin I found a decent solution.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: self.myData,
    columnDefs: [{ field: 'firstName', cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><input type="text" ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD" /></div>' }]
};
```